# IsVisibleChanged is calledn even I set a control to 'Collapsed'

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm using a control and its IsVisibleChanged event.

If I set the control to be Collapsed, IsVisibleChanged will never triggered and that's what I want.

But the problem is, when I set the Visibility by a Binding (the binding data converter returns Collapsed), IsVisibleChanged will be triggered twice, first to visible then to invisible.

I set 2 breakpoints, one in IsVisibleChanged handler and one in binding data's converter. The first breakpoint stops first and then the second one.

It seems that a default value is used then the binding value is applied. How can I avoid the unwanted IsVisibleChanged event? by changing the default value? but how?

Thanks.

Comment: Post us code. What do you bind exactly to what?

Comment: Just tried a few tests and I can't seem to make the IsVisibleChanged event get raised twice, I only get it once when the value actually changes, you'll have to provide code examples for this one (stand alone samples if possible)

Comment: Yes, @Andy, @dev hedgehog, you are correct. It's my mistake. I assigned the binding by changing the DataContext after component initialization, so the binding took effect later then default value. It's fixed by assign the value of DataContect earlier than `InitializeComponent()`.